# passing dynamic attribute from ADF to javascript

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm trying to pass an attribute from  to javascript function using  , it is work but display "previous value" in the first time and display the correct value at the second time.

Here is my code

ADF:

```
 <af:form id="f1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_js_page.f1}">
        <af:inputText label="Name" id="it1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_js_page.it1}" value="#{backingBeanScope.backing_js_page.name}"
                      autoSubmit="true" partialTriggers="it1">

        </af:inputText>
        <af:button text="Say Hello" id="b1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_js_page.b1}">
              <af:clientAttribute name="name" value="#{backingBeanScope.backing_js_page.it1.value}"/>

            <af:clientListener method="sayHello" type="click"/>
        </af:button>
        <af:resource type="javascript" source="/resources/js/hello.js"/>
    </af:form>
```

Javascript code:

```
function sayHello(evt) {
var comp = evt.getSource();
alert(comp.getProperty('name'));
evt.cancel();
 }
```

Comment: Hey @jmt, if the answer helped don't forget to accept it : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can run a javascript function inside your adf bean :

jsff:

```
<af:button text="Say Hello" id="b1" actionListener="#{Scope.Bean.onClick}">
    </af:button>
```

adf bean :

```
public void onClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    String myJavaVariable = "hello World";
    String jsCode="alert('"+myJavaVariable+"');"; //YOUR JS SCRIPT WITH JAVA VARIABLES EMBEDED
    this.executeJavaScript(jsCode);
    }

public static void executeJavaScript(String jsCode) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExtendedRenderKitService erks = Service.getRenderKitService(context, ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
    erks.addScript(context, jsCode);
}
```

Comment: The executeJavaScript function is taken from a series of convenience functions for dealing with ADF Bindings : ADFUtils http://jdeveloper-adf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/TGPrototype2/ViewController/src/com/tgslc/defaultManagement/utils/ADFUtils.java